# Using bash programmable completion (TAB) with folder name that starts with '@'

Tags: bash

Can I configure the bash "auto-complete" to understand folder names than begin with `@`? Currently it seems to try and list network locations.

Comment: What version of `bash` on what system? When I run bash, it auto-completes just fine with files/folders starting with `@`. You could try escaping it first `\@...`. I found that works with other characters that seem to thwart auto-completion.

Comment: The network-location listing isn't default out-of-the-box behavior -- your linux distro has presumably installed something that does that.

Comment: BTW, questions about using the shell interactively, as opposed to writing scripts for it, are generally a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autocomplete files starting with a `@` by escaping with a backslash (`\`), as mentioned by @lurker in the comments, **or** by preceding the expression with a quotation mark (`'` | `"`):

**backslash `\`:**

`cd node_modules/\@myf` -> `[tab]` -> `cd node_modules/\@myfolder`

**single quote `'`:**

`cd 'node_modules/@myf` -> `[tab]` -> `cd 'node_modules/@myfolder'`

**double quote `"`:**

`cd "node_modules/@myf` -> `[tab]` -> `cd "node_modules/@myfolder"`